# Rectangular electrical box doesn't fit. How can I install receptacle?

Tags: electrical

I'm trying to install a [duplex receptacle](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/1d8b16f1-03f8-4be0-a84f-f0cd573280bd/svn/white-leviton-outlets-receptacles-m02-cbr20-wmp-64_1000.jpg). The problem is that the hole in the wall doesn't have the threads for the screws that hold the receptacle to the wall.

I purchased a [regular rectangular steel electrical box](http://is2.ecplaza.com/ecplaza2/products/7/79/793/1722303914/rectangular-electrical-boxsteel.jpg), but it doesn't fit in the wall; it's too big.

What options do I have?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a standard drywall-and-studs wall?

Comment: The box you have pictured is made for surface mounting on a shop wall.   You may want a different style "old work" box if you're trying to recess it into an existing wall.  More detail of the situation would help, such as a picture taken of the space this box is to fill.

Comment: Is it possible the hole is not intended for mounting electrical equipment?  or could the correct holes be covered up by paint or leveling compound?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you are trying to install an outlet box in a hole intended for low voltage equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Is this already an existing box (just with damaged threads) if so then you can use some 1" #10 wood screws instead of the mounting screws that come with the outlet, this I a common problem I run in to on service calls (I am a apprentice electrician).

The other thing is that box you purchased is not a typical wall box instead you may want to try an 1104 box like this [image]

And if you are mounting it to the drywall instead of the stud (common when drywall is already up) use some f-clips to support it[image] it is hard to describe the installation in text so try [this simple youtube video](https://youtu.be/pwziu8RGF4A) or you can use a rework box such as this as they are much easier to use but a bit more expensive (still under $10) [image]

I hope this helps

Comment: You should edit your answer and remove the reference to wood screws. Refer to "**Article 406.5 Receptacle Mounting.**  Receptacles shall be mounted in identified boxes or assemblies. The boxes or assemblies shall be securely fastened in place unless otherwise permitted elsewhere in this Code. **Screws used for the purpose of attaching receptacles to a box shall be of the type provided with a listed receptacle, or shall be machine screws having 32 threads per inch or part of listed assemblies or systems, in accordance with the manufacturer's instructions.**" Wood screws are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that's what I need. How would I search for a "1104 box" in an online store?